# Program to develop a 3d racing game with traffic rules

Tags: programming-languages

Which is the best and suitable programming language that I can develop a game of racing cars along a street with other road users, like in the city streets, with traffic rules?

Comment: Most programming languages are suitable for this purpose: we need more information about the platform you'll be running on, is it 2D or 3D, et cetera.

Comment: The game will be run on a windows platform, 3D

Comment: this is a very subjective question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standards would be OpenGL with C++, DirectX with C++ or XNA with C#/VB.

If you are new to 3D graphics and game development, XNA would have the smoothest learning curve in my opinion.

Comment: But XNA isn't as funny as OpenGL.

Comment: Why is OpenGL funny? I don't get it!

Comment: Okay, thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: thanks guys...i a have already learned something and i am into it...

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to programming in general, I suggest using a tool like Stencyl: http://www.stencyl.com/ It may not allow you to do 3D but it's an easy introduction to something that can quickly become overwhelming. Alternatively you could use Unity http://unity3d.com which is easy to get in to without too much programming.

If you're already familiar with programming languages, I suggest you use the one that you're most familiar with. Even if your most familiar language is Python, you can use PyGame or whatever to write it.

In truth, there's no "best" language, there's just different languages, each with advantages and disadvantages. Most major studio engines are written in C or C++, with a few in C#. These languages are difficult to write game engines though. If you're not already a programmer, make it easy on yourself and start with something simple :)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Java with the LWJGL library for making 3D OpenGL games. Java is also very cross-platform, but the downside is that it's kindof slow. OpenGl is also very hard to get started with

Comment: I think opengl is simple but as c++ is declining i prefer java.